# Setting Sharepoint File Field Attributes

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In out SP site, we have a library with files. These are files associated with a user. We now cstomized the user's profiles to accept a list of files. And now, to this list of files in the user's profile, we would like to add a reference to the file so that the user doesn't have to upload again.

Current Library:
    /personal/my/User Files/[filename]

So, I was wondering how to do this? The data looks like this in the new User Files field (JSON):

```
{
    [
        {
            "Id":"1",
            "Title":"Test",
            "Url":"\/personal\/my\/User+Files\/testfile.doc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a csv file that I iterate over. The csv file contains the user name:filename pairs.

The Id value has to be gotten from the SP instance libarary at that location for that file.

Powershell code:

```
$upAttribute = "UserFiles"
$profile_info = Import-Csv profiles.csv

foreach ($row in $profile_info) {
    $userId = $row.user # User ID
    $fullAdAccount = $adAccount += $userId

    #Check to see if user profile exists
    if ($profileManager.UserExists($fullAdAccount))
    {
        $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($fullAdAccount)
        $upAttributeValue += $row.filename # Filename

        # CODE ??????

        $up.Commit()
    }
}
```

That is the all the data that I have.

Thanks for any and all help.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to add the custom property to the User Profile like so:

http://www.paulgrimley.com/2011/02/adding-custom-user-profile-property-to.html

Then this should help you out:

http://get-spscripts.com/2010/07/modify-single-value-user-profile.html

```
#Get user profile and change the value
$up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($adAccount)
$up[$upAttribute].Value = $upAttributeValue
$up.Commit()
```